# No sound and wifi after installing kernel headers ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, sound, kernel, iwlwifi

I recently installed updated kernel headers

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

`sudo apt autoremove`

Upon restarting, I've lost my wifi and sound input and ouput. It seems to be driver issue, since when I run: 
`sudo lshw -class network`

```
Output:
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 03
       serial: 20:47:47:c5:93:90
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.2-3 ip=200.200.200.142 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:46 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7243000-f7243fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 59
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7000000-f7001fff
```

For the sound input and output, I only see dummy output. The command `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` gives me:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
```

and `pacmd list-cards` gives the output:

`0 card(s) available.`

I copied over the wifi driver from intel's website (https://www.intel.co.za/content/www/za/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) over to my firmware folder, but not sure what to do after that.